# Get the least significant digit as scalar to add or substract with (from a decimal.js object)

Tags: javascript, decimal, currency

i am working with money values here. I have an unknown amount of money of a unkown currency (compiletime unknown ofc). I have multiple targets to divide that amout to.

One example:

Amount is $3.02 and i will divide with three friends so each will get $1 leaving 2 cents to spare.
Now as the amount has to be correct at the end i split up the remainder between the parties untill all cents to spare are gone.

Note that the same has to work for yapanese yen. They don't have cents. There it would be for example 32 divided by 3 equals 10 each and 2 to spare.

In the following code `cents` is a decimal.js value with the remainder of the split mentioned above (e.g "0.02" or just "2").

```js
for (let i = 0; !cents.isZero(); i++) {
    const transactionData = transactionsData[i]
    const newAmountCents = new decimal.Decimal(transactionData.amount).plus(new decimal.Decimal("0.01"))
    console.log(`New Amount: ${newAmountCents}`)
    transactionData.amount = newAmountCents.toString()
    newCents = newCents.minus(new decimal.Decimal("0.01"))
}
```

As you can probably see my problem. I am adding "0.01" here and subtracting the same. But as i mentioned this is variable accoring to the decimal places of the underlying currency. How can i extract the correct "unit" and replace the "0.01" with the correct amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can go this way and create sort of parse function, which will get currency value and number of shares and returns reminder and lowest possible currency value

```js
const parseCoin = (coin, shares) => {
  // How mutch zeros after . to use
  // Parse coin value as string and
  // find it out:
  // 3.00 -> 2
  // 3 -> 0
  let match = String(coin).match(/\.(.*)/);
  const decimalFixed = match ? match[1].length : 0;

  // Modulus
  let remainder = (Number(coin) % shares).toFixed(decimalFixed);

  // Find smallest available value
  const smallestValue = 1 / 10 ** decimalFixed;
  
  // Return object
  return { remainder, smallestValue };
}

// Test
console.log(parseCoin(3.02, 3));
console.log(parseCoin(32, 3));
console.log(parseCoin(2, 2));
console.log(parseCoin(4, 3));
console.log(parseCoin('3.000', 3));
```

Comment: Okay, this also leads the correct way. I can work with that. Thank you

Comment: I've updated my function to correctly match values like `3.00`. If my answer helps you, please vote)

Comment: With the examples it now is really good and exactly what i was looking for. I will use your code instead of mine, as this is more flexible and works with all currencies. So your answer is the accepted one. Tanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Have your "0.01" as a string variable that is set when the currency is set

```
const smallestUnitString = "0.01" // In practice you would replace this 
// with a function call that looks up the currency name in a table, and
// returns "1" for Yen, and "0.01" for most other currencies.


for (let i = 0; !cents.isZero(); i++) {
    const transactionData = transactionsData[i]
    const newAmountCents = new decimal.Decimal(transactionData.amount).plus(new decimal.Decimal(smallestUnitString))
    console.log(`New Amount: ${newAmountCents}`)
    transactionData.amount = newAmountCents.toString()
    newCents = newCents.minus(new decimal.Decimal(smallestUnitString))
}
```

Comment: This of course would work, but this would lead to additional database calls everytime i want to calculate this. I guess the same should be achievable by some simple string manipulation shouldn't it? Trying to avoid saving more than need data to the database (on the frontend i don't have a problem as Joda Money handels this for me)

Comment: Yes, but string manipulation of what? I don't see in this program snippet you have provided, where there is any information about (a) what the smallest unit is, or (b) what the currency is. Surely that is stored somewhere?

Comment: Yes i have the currency stored with the amount of course, but not the number of fractional digits. But for a) we do know at this point that `cents` holds the remainder of the split between for example 3 parties. Which means for doller `cents` is either 0.01 or 0.02 there is no other possibility. For Yen it would be either 1 or 2. As everything above is already splitted equally between parties. But writing this i realised how to solve the problem. I will write an answer

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that i can just use `coins.dp()` and setup a string accordingly

```
function getSmallestUnit(coins: decimal.Decimal) :string{
    const dp = coins.dp()
    if(dp===0){
        return "1"
    }else if(dp===1){
        return "0.1"
    }else if(dp===2){
        return "0.01"
    }else{
        return "0.001"
    }
    //Continues if there are more currencies that have more decimal places than 3 (have to check this)
 }
```

I think this should do the trick. Have to check this. Otherwise the answer of [@tarkh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63413211/4338278) will work as well:)